# Why c++ allows default template argument that can never be used?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, default-arguments

If I have a function template that has default argument for its template parameter and that function takes a non-default parameter of the type parameter then what's the point in the language to allow that default argument that'll never be used? :

```
template <class T = int>
void foo(T x){cout << x << endl;}

int main()
{

    foo("hi"); // T is char const *
    foo(); // error
}
```

As you can see `T=int` can never be used because the function doesn't have a default parameter thus the compiler in this context always deduces the type of `T` from the argument passed to `foo`.

Comment: Does your function take no parameters?  What would it mean to call a function that needs a parameter without it?

Comment: Almost certainly because it's relatively expensive to try to actually prove that type inference can always succeed for some given function, and relatively pointless to issue a warning when it can prove that it's in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But it *can* be used. Here's an example.

```cpp
auto* foo_ptr = &foo<>; // The default template argument is used.
```

A function call expression is not the only context where a function template's arguments need to be figured out.

Comment: Perhaps a more common example: `foo({})`. (More common when you have something like an algorithm on a container defaulting to the value type.)

Answer (score 3):

Although default parameters are usually used for non deduced parameters, taking the address of the function (`&foo`) uses them too.

Answer (score 2):

Another example:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T = int>
void coutType() {
    cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

int main() {
    // default
    coutType();
    // non-default
    coutType<double>();
}
```

Output with Clang++

```cpp
int
double
```

Comment: Not strictly relevant to the question, though it does partially answer it in that this is the main intended use case for default template arguments (and there was no reason to ban them in the OP's case, particularly as other use cases exist, as shown in the other answers).

Comment: Is posting additional example answers not recommended? If it is not recommended I will refrain from posting additional example answers in the future.

Comment: @ColonD In general, posting additional example answers can be beneficial. However, in this specific case, the OP has indicated an awareness of this sort of example, so I'm not sure of this answer's value. (The OP called out the lack of a default for the function parameter. If there was a default for the function parameter, then the function could be called without arguments, which is basically your example. So it looks like the question is intended to avoid this example.)

Comment: @JaMiT ah, I could not see OP's awareness so my mistake

Comment: @ColonD I wasn't complaining, I was explaining my upvote ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm sorry if it seems I perceived your comment in the negative way, I am just trying to improve my answers, I appreciate your comment

Answer (score 0):

> what's the point in the language to allow [X]?

Better: what would be the point in prohibiting [X]?

There is value in simplicity. I would give the burden of proof to the side that wants to make the language more complicated. The language allows a template parameter to have a default value. The language allows a template parameter to be deduced when the function is directly invoked. It is simpler to allow these to co-exist than to add a prohibition against using both. Hence I would ask why prohibit, rather than ask why allow. If there is no compelling reason for the complication, then stick to simple. Being allowed to do something does not force one to do it. And maybe someone (like StoryTeller and Dani) will find a use for that something.

Of course, simplicity is not the ultimate criterion. If harm would come from [X], then that would likely outweigh simplicity concerns. Complications can be justified. However, complications should not be introduced just because something seems useless.

*On the other hand, one could reasonably ask if [X] can be put to use. And maybe that was the real question, even if the OP did not realize it. Still, I thought I would put up one answer addressing the question-as-phrased.*